# Using Register Variables in VimScript

Tags: vim, viml

I have the following code in vim Script(File name: file):

```
:execute "normal /\This\<CR>gg"
:let i=1
:execute "normal nxxcwThat".@=i
```

I am executing this code on the following file(File name: out):

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

I am using the following run command:

```
vim -s file out
```

And the output is:

```
This is line 1
That 1 is line 2
```

I do not understand why is space getting printed between `That` and `1`.
Also, I am slightly confused in how to use register variables when writing a vimscript. Could someone please explain?

Comment: You could use `i` directly.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bug. But is there a reason, you are using the expression-register to access the variable?

What works is to use, which looks more readable anyhow:

```
:execute "normal nxxcwThat".i
```